# Where can I find files saved in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder while developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

To my understanding, WinRT apps store their application data in

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Packages`

My Windows Phone 8.1 application seems to have its own folder there as well, with an odd name like

`App.aba911777.a60e8.a46c0.aa90d.a5038d92d276e_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

However, when I browse the directory, I cannot find any of the files I've saved to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. They are definitely there, because if I re-run my app in the emulator (which hasn't been closed at all), can find the cached files. Presumably these files are saved somewhere on my actual hard drive; where would they be?

(`LocalFolder.Path` gives me `C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\2cdc8aaf-b7fe-4bcb-992a-18ad6f140771_b83k3kj2dpxdw\LocalState` but I'm not sure how to find that on my hard drive)

Comment: To get the files from the App you can use for example [IsolatedStorageExplorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx) or [Isolated Storage Spy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @Romasz can you add that as an answer? I finally stumbled across a question yesterday that pointed out that the way of accessing files via WinRT or the "old" IsolatedStorage methods are actually pointing at the same physical location.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ed75af37-a42f-489f-a2e0-58b6725bbcd4/are-isolatedstorage-and-applicationdatalocalfolder-always-the-same-thing?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ed75af37-a42f-489f-a2e0-58b6725bbcd4/are-isolatedstorage-and-applicationdatalocalfolder-always-the-same-thing?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ed75af37-a42f-489f-a2e0-58b6725bbcd4/are-isolatedstorage-and-applicationdatalocalfolder-always-the-same-thing?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yes, the *old* Isolated Storage is the same as [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465099.aspx) :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To transfer/access files on Windows Phone Emulator (also works with device) you can use:

- Isolated Storage Explorer tool - [here is a good link how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629254.aspx), and [also one useful here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx).
- a very nice tool is [Isolated Storage Spy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) - which now supports also WP8.1
- [Windows Phone Power Tools from here](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) - you will have to check if that already works with WP8.1.

Comment: Isolated Storage Spy is *very* nice :)

Comment: "Windows Phone Power Tools" - Worked great

Even it has features like launch the dev apps.

Answer (score 1):

Search your SQLite db file in "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\".

Answer (score 0):

localFolder.Path gives you correct location. You are not able to find that folder because **AppData** is been hidden. Please change your PC settings to view this folder.

Thanks